# How to Create Time Lapse duration field

Tags: case, time

In our organisation multiple teams working on a single Business process (record type of `Case`). Means multiple teams works on a single `Case`.

So, we have a requirement to calculate how much time taken for single team to hand over to other team. In my requirement I need to calculate time duration for first team.

We have a user called **team order** they will create the cases.

So I need to give time 24 hours for this team to handover the case to other team. Through change the status of the case to particular one.

Once they change the status to particular one I need to show time lapse taken for creation to handover.

And if handover didn't happen with in 22 hours. I need to alert case owner about current time lapse through mail.

Please provide suggestions to work on these type of cases.

Comment: This question sounds pretty broad, and you haven't shown us what you've tried so far. As is, it reads like a 'do my work for me' request. What have you tried? Where, precisely, are you stuck? If you just need some initial direction, this sounds like you need a separate object to track the time spent on each `Case`, a trigger to update things when the team (or status) changes, and a workflow rule with a time-based action.

Comment: Sorry but i am not getting any idea to set up time based field because i need to get duration of case created to handover to some team.But actually no time fields are not there in sfdc

Answer (score 1):

Better, leverage Entitlement Process and Milestone functionality.

For this here is the approach:

- Define Business Hours
- Define Entitlement Process
- Define Milestone

When case is getting created you will update EntitlementId on the Case and automatically case will be tracked by milestone.

If milestone is violated, then you can configure email alerts and automatically mail will get sent. You can also send warning email before violation.

Refer [Entitlement Processes](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=entitlements_process_overview.htm&type=0) and [Entitlement Management trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trails/service_cloud/modules/entitlements)

Otherwise, without Entitlement & Milestone, you have to write your own logic for your business case.